Would it be okay to have a predictor that overlaps with the variable used as a random effect?
I will work with a predictor based on a Countries' Tightness index (numerical), so there’s one value for each country. I'll be collecting data in 50 countries, but I expect the number of participants to vary a lot between countries (minimum expected in a country is 100 participants).
Because of this, I'm thinking about adding country as a random effect (factor). But most countries have unique predictor values, with five countries sharing the same Tightness score.
I'm worried this might make the model singular or perturb the results, assuming that the random effect for country could end up eating most of the variability of the predictor. Is this something I should be concerned about? (I don't have the data yet, but I know the outcome variables will be dichotomous).
Example of the expected structure of the data:
participant_id     outcome_variable    tightness    country  
           x01                    1         -0.2        USA 
           x01                    0         -0.2        USA  
           x01                    0         -0.2        USA  
           x01                    1         -0.2        USA  
           x02                    1         -0.2        USA 
           x02                    1         -0.2        USA  
           x02                    0         -0.2        USA  
           x02                    1         -0.2        USA  
           x03                    1          0.3        UK 
           x03                    1          0.3        UK  
           x03                    1          0.3        UK  
           x03                    1          0.3        UK  
           x04                    0          0.5        FR 
           x04                    1          0.5        FR  
           x04                    1          0.5        FR  
           x04                    0          0.5        FR  

Expected model:
glmer(outcome_variable ~ tightness + (1 | participant_id) + (1 | country), data, family=binomial)
I want to see if the adherence to certain norms (outcome) are more prevalent in countries with higher Tightness or not.

Please can you clarify a few things: 1. What is your research question ? Please clarify what you mean about "pairs" ? At first I thought your concern was that you have a predictor that has the same value for all countries (ie that this variable varies only varies between countries, and not within), but having re-read it, I'm not sure sure.

Only a suggestion: Have you considered simulating data and fitting the model to it? You can vary the number of participants per country, number of observations per participant, rate of incomplete / missing observations, form of the relationship between tightness and the odds of Y = 1, etc. This should help you understand the behavior of the model.

In your mixed model, the country effects are random intercepts. The effect of tightness (the slope in the linear predictor) is a fixed effect (ie. it's modeled at the population level, not at country level.) So you should be able to estimate it. Another thing to consider is the linearity assumption explicit in Y ~ tightness + (...).
